# Data Envrionments, True DB grids and VB6

Tags: vb6, recordset, truedbgrid

I have finally been able to get all the columns I wanted to show up in the data environment and have added an additional command to try and pull those values from a local DB into the grid.

The issue I am running into is the values are not appearing inside my grid.

I have it running the correct command to pull in the data I believe: I took that same query and ran it on the local DB and it does output the values I expect. I then clone the Environment command to a record set.

```
If gbEnableD2D Then
    If DataEnvironment7.rscmdMeterReadsDistinctD2D.State <> adStateOpen Then
        DataEnvironment7.cmdMeterReadsDistinctD2D
    End If
Else

If gbEnableD2D Then
    Set rsDevices = DataEnvironment7.rscmdMeterReadsDistinctD2D.Clone
Else

' Display all the columns I want to display
```

From there I can determine the columns do show up as intended but in the display as well as using the watching system I can not access the `MeterReadsDistinctD2D` nor does the record set contain the values but does have the fields I expect.

Any thoughts on to why this would occur or how I could go about tracking down how to determine how I can see if these values are in my data environment or if they are in there why they are not being passed to the record set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the TrueDBGrid is in Bound Mode, then bind it to a Data Control and set the Recordset/Recordsource of the Data Control to your SQL Query. Make sure the ConnectionString of the Data Control successfully connects to your database.

Comment: I dont recall what I did to solve this but is has been solved thank you though